# how can I load jquery.min.js via mod_pagespeed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mod-pagespeed

I added this file to .htaccess file:

```
ModPagespeedLibrary 84234 i6FmF6RqXu7ms5FO_JWdB //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
```

and what must I do now?

I have same file in my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I must remove last one or change? how?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ModPagespeedLibrary` option is used by the [`canonicalize_javascript_libraries`](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-canonicalize-js) filter. Its purpose is to modify links to JS library files hosted on your site to point to the version hosted on the ajax.googleapis.com CDN. If your site is already using the google CDN version, which it looks like it is, then this filter won't provide any benefit for you.